# Gradle Build stuck at generate debug sources

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Gradle gets stuck when I try to build on the task [:android:generateDebugSources].

I've left it running for hours without a successful build.

I've tried it in Android Studio 1.0.0, 0.8.1, with Gradle versions 2.1.1, 1.12, 1.14, Android plugin versions 0.12.+ and 0.14.4 using the default wrapper as well as local distributions. I've reinstalled Android Studio and rebooted without any luck. Also tried File --> invalidate caches/Restart.

Here is my android package's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories
        {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {

maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 13
    versionName "onBoarding"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.8.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.3.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
}
```

And then my project-level gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tryin deleting dependencies (imported libs) and start adding them one-by-one, each time using `Clean Project` and see where the error / freeze occurs.

Comment: Still getting stuck, even without dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried maybe updating the Android Studio to newer version ? it might come with new gradle updates to assist you.
I am just checking my gradle.build file, and they are really different. 
I am using Maven, however, I am not initializing it in my buildscript! 

Have you tried using Maven with: `File -> Project Structure -> App -> Dependencies -> Add` ?

And with leaving your buildscript default (your's not default, according to mine and I didn't manually change it).

Comment: Added my dependencies through `Project Structure` and took out everything from the buildscript and still stuck...

Comment: Use this answer solved my problem on ubuntu x64 :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31095817/1638277

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! Changing the `buildToolsVersion` from `21.1.1` to `20` yielded a successful build.

Comment: in my case there was no build.gradle file.

Comment: We use `buildToolsVersion`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also, just install the correct version of the tools.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I spent a lot of time in this problem and read at least 30 answers until I found out what was hapenning.
I constantly got a message that another aplication was locking a file that Android-Studio needed to complete gradle building. Finally, I found out that it was Avast. So I simply deactivated it and the build finished successfully, but it still took a long time (about 10 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Tried below option and it worked!

1. Add below properties to your `.gradle` file

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

2. Set `SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT` environment variable to 30 in windows and restart your system.
   Second solution credit goes to [semuzaboi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105176/).