# Android Studio fails to build new project, timed out while wating for slave aapt process

Tags: android, android-studio

I've installed Android Studio 1.2, and created a new project. When I attempt to build, it hangs. This is in the Gradle Console, along with about 20 other copies, with different numbers after png-cruncher_:

```
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:204)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: "along with about 20 other copies, with different numbers after png-cruncher_:", what? Is this a new project?

Comment: Yes, this happened for me with a new project.  There were more errors further up in the console, and all was fixed after I installed some 32-bit support libs.

Comment: I have this same problem on Mac OS/X 10.7.5 Lion. Installing the Android Support Library, described below, does not help. I am running Android Studio 1.3.2.  The project I am trying to build is one of the SDK Samples: ActionBarCompat-Basic.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36826562/1770868

Comment: See discussion at [Android Issue 188627](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188627).

Answer (score 58):

I had the same problem with Debian Jessie for AMD64. I did this, and it works:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Comment: saved my life on ubuntu x64

Comment: Thank you. As a note, `apt-get update` is required before installing those packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot with my ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Could you please explain why this should solve anything?

Comment: To be fair: it says in the official docs that you need "sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32bz2-1.0" https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html -> linux

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issue whilst running Android Studio 1.5.1 for Windows 8.1 (64 bit), and what I did to solve the problem was by adding the following two system environment variables:

```
SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT = 30
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
```

(**Please note**: The path for the JAVA_HOME system environment variable is dependant on where your JDK is located and that the version of your JDK may differ from the example above).

Comment: Setting `SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT` done it for me  cheers, mr beveridge 

Comment: @Luke Beveridge: where to set Enviornment variable ?

Comment: @AndroidGeeks Assuming that you are using Windows8/Windows10, you can navigate to this by opening the Control panel then clicking: System --> Advanced System settings --> Environment Variables.

Once here, you will be able to create new environment variables or edit existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on Windows 8.1 64 bits and what ended up solving everything was running gradle in the command line in debug mode, on the project folder:

```
gradlew -d assembleDebug
```

Running without the `-d` flag had the same problem.

After running the first time, everything was ok, I could even clean and rebuild my project.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and what was missing were a library to be installed on the SDK.
Just installing the correct library immediately solved the problem.
In my case was the Android Support Library, as I was creating a navigation drawer.
The errors shown in the gradle console didn't give me a clue for the solution, and didn't helped me at all.
Click on SDK manager, and click on the tab SDK Tools, check "Android Support Library" and click apply.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug reported here --> https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188627

The workaround on Mac is to reboot your computer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15291327)

Comment: The answer is, restart your machine to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on a Linux x64 machine you probably miss some required libraries. [The offical sdk guide states:](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)

> **Required libraries for 64-bit machines:**
>
> If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:
>
> `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32bz2-1.0`
>
> If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:
>
> `sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686`

of course don't forget to

```
sudo apt-get update
```

first.

Comment: For fedora 24 following command does the work for me:    sudo dnf install compat-libstdc++-296.i686 compat-libstdc++-33.i686 compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64 ncurses-libs.i686

Answer (score 1):

By pausing the antivirus I don't have anymore that problem, or better by making a rule at the antivirus in order to accept a given '.class' filename recognized as trojan, then banned at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall if it is coming in your way. Disabling my firewall works for me but i don't know if it's the right fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with CentOS 6.5. Before this error, I found the cause of the error, as follows.

```
AAPT err(Facade for 1129807373): xxx/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by xxx/lib64/libc++.so)
```

“**libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found**” . The highest version of CentOS 6.5 is 2.12, and we need to upgrade to 2.14.

Display the installed glibc version:

```
# rpm -qa | grep glibc
```

To download the corresponding RPM package. -> [ftp.redsleeve.org/pub/steam/](http://ftp.redsleeve.org/pub/steam/)

Install the RPM package as follows:

```
# rpm -Uvh glibc-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-common-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-devel-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-headers-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm --nodeps --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled 1.2 and installed 1.1, but it did't work.

Because I used local SDK installed previously, I uninstalled and reinstalled 1.1 and installed SDK to new path.

After I used SDK in new path, I don't have those errors any more.

And I upgraded Android Studio to 1.2, and also I don't have errors.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading Build Tools rescued me.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this please. how you did it?