# I can't build project in Android Studio on Ubuntu. Gradle running build takes infinity

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I have the newest distribution of Ubuntu(15.04).
I have installed the newest Java(1.8 and Android Studio with SDK, but when i want to build project it's building running application and it takes infinity time.(It building all time without any error).Even if I want to stop building, then stopping gradle building takes infinity.
Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio fails to build new project, timed out while wating for slave aapt process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111443/android-studio-fails-to-build-new-project-timed-out-while-wating-for-slave-aapt)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had identical problem and finally I solved this by those three commands in Terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

I found that here:
[Android Studio fails to build new project, timed out while wating for slave aapt process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111443/android-studio-fails-to-build-new-project-timed-out-while-wating-for-slave-aapt)

Comment: You forgot about "apt-get update" before installing new packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable Offline work for Gradle, that's work for me.

Do it via File-->Settings-->Buid,Execution...-->Build Tools-->Gradle.

then check the offline work.