# Android Studio startup stuck in gradle running

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I just install android studio in my ubuntu 16.04 gnome, then i try to create a new project but it stucks at the gradle build.. The Gradle Message says :

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

You can see the screen shoot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JXbK.png). So, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use ubuntu or know the answer but these links seem to be dealing with the same issue:

1) [How to fix Android Studio getting stuck executing Gradle tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629368/how-to-fix-android-studio-getting-stuck-executing-gradle-tasks)

The solution to this one was to install `libz.so.1` and you can find installation instructions here: [libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256866/libz-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

2) [I can't build project in Android Studio on Ubuntu. Gradle running build takes infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165978/i-cant-build-project-in-android-studio-on-ubuntu-gradle-running-build-takes-in)

The solution to the second one was to use these two commands in Terminal:

**sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386**

**sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386**

3) [Android Studio gradle takes too long to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build)

I'm not sure the third link is as relevant, as it solves the problem of gradle builds taking a long time, not the problem of gradle builds getting stuck, but it still may be helpful information.

The solution to the third link was to go to:

> In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
>
> Check the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX0Or.png]

Comment: i think the first link works fine for me... thank you