# Cannot build android app

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-gradle-plugin

Today I've upgraded my Parse.com library version from 1.9.3 to 1.10.2.

Since then I can't build my app or sync the gradle files. It shows this message on the Gradle Console:

```
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_19" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:204)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can you please help me? I can't do anything...

Comment: Did you try `setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds` ?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a user variable or system variable?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/31095817/5202007

Comment: I've returned to version 1.9.3 and everything is ok now