# Gradle Build Running Taking too long

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have installed Android studio in Ubuntu **14.04**.I tried to clean the project but it taking too long its already been 1 hr since the gradle is running. In my Gradle console I got the error like :

> Exception in thread "png-cruncher_8" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed
>   out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute
>   at /home/files/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run
>   successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment
>   variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds  at
>   com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)

can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111443/android-studio-fails-to-build-new-project-timed-out-while-wating-for-slave-aapt

Answer (score 0):

I having same problem and solved by installing `lib32z1` with command

```
sudo apt install lib32z1
```

I got my solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739532/why-building-of-gradle-cant-be-finished).