# android studio is taking much time to open project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, projects

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96rUb.png)

I installed Android Studio and when I am going to open the project this is taking too long time than before.
what is the solution i get for this ?

Comment: It is downloading dependencies used by your project. How is your internet connection? Are you behind a Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

this helped me, try to work offline:
in settings> Gradle > Global Gradle settings > Offline work

you can take a look at this answares too:

[Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up)

[Any solution for Android Studio slow gradle build and high disk usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861943/any-solution-for-android-studio-slow-gradle-build-and-high-disk-usage)