# Gradle build error(Android Studio 2.2.2 )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I install Android Studio 2.2.2 with the necessary packages on Debian Jessie and check updates

I have 2 errors when gradle building start:

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crunching Cruncher launcher.png failed, see logs
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

I was looking for an answer on this forum and I tried to solve this errors by editing the png files in the /res/drawable folder.I used **Pinta** image editor and save files as **launcher.png**

I also checked gradle.build files and made sure that the SDK build tool versions shown there lasts version(25.0.0)

**module gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.project"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.jar')
}
```

**project level gradle file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Gradle console**

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 1101934): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
AAPT err(Facade for 29345672): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Thread(png-cruncher_5): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Thread(png-cruncher_4): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crunching Cruncher launcher.png failed, see logs

AAPT err(Facade for 14139714): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

AAPT err(Facade for 3636584): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Thread(png-cruncher_3): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Thread(png-cruncher_2): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

AAPT err(Facade for 5293242): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Thread(png-cruncher_1): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Process list not empty
Thread(png-cruncher_3): queue not cleaned

while shutting downpng-cruncher_3
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.shutdown(QueuedCruncher.java:161)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.shutdown(WorkQueue.java:169)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.end(QueuedCruncher.java:309)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.lambda$compile$0(AaptV1.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thread(png-cruncher_4): queue not cleaned

while shutting downpng-cruncher_4
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.shutdown(QueuedCruncher.java:161)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.shutdown(WorkQueue.java:169)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.end(QueuedCruncher.java:309)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.lambda$compile$0(AaptV1.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thread(png-cruncher_1): queue not cleaned

while shutting downpng-cruncher_1
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.shutdown(QueuedCruncher.java:161)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.shutdown(WorkQueue.java:169)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.end(QueuedCruncher.java:309)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.lambda$compile$0(AaptV1.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thread(png-cruncher_2): queue not cleaned

while shutting downpng-cruncher_2
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.shutdown(QueuedCruncher.java:161)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.shutdown(WorkQueue.java:169)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.end(QueuedCruncher.java:309)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.lambda$compile$0(AaptV1.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thread(png-cruncher_5): queue not cleaned

while shutting downpng-cruncher_5
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.shutdown(QueuedCruncher.java:161)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.shutdown(WorkQueue.java:169)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.end(QueuedCruncher.java:309)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.lambda$compile$0(AaptV1.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crunching Cruncher launcher.png failed, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.213 secs
```

Please help me to fix this errors

Thanks

Comment: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111443/android-studio-fails-to-build-new-project-timed-out-while-wating-for-slave-aapt

Comment: Look at my answer here, may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44892542/3412127

Answer (score 5):

change buildtoolversion in your gradle file

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0" // change here with your installed buildtool version

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.project"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 25
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I fix this error in Debian 32bit:

**upload Android SDK Build Tools version 19.1**

**Project Structure -> Properties -> Build Tools version 19.1**

after then project build without errors

Answer (score 0):

replace build.gradle with this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.project"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 25
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.jar')
}
```