# Android-Studio-2.3 Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi there I'm new on Android-Studio-2.3

I have these error messages that pop up :
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

I've been on many sites but I cannot find a solution to this problem
By the way I have already tried to downgrade my gradle to 23.0.0 or 23.0.1 but it still doesn't work. Android-Studio asks me to download the 25.0.0 version but when I do that, the error messages above still come up !

Does anybody have a solution, I would be very gratefull :)

Comment: Did you get any solution? I'm facing the same problem in Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem and coudn't solve it either. BUT:
I assume, that you tried to install android studio on Ubuntu? If I am right, you could check, which OS you have. If it is an 64bit os you could try it with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that I'm working on Linux Ubuntu but it is a 32 bit os

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Great Man ! It worked for me..! since i am trying this error from last 5 days and solved it in one line only.

Answer (score 0):

YOU MAY WANT TO CHECK IN YOUR APPLICATION LEVEL

> build.gradle

FILE for the version of gradle you are trying to compile with. When i used gradle 2.3.3 this problem occured but then i changed back to 2.2.3 and everything worked. I think the issue is with the gradle version for android studio 2.3.3. Important to note that 2.3.3 works mostly with compileSDK 25+