# Asking about correct support library in android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

What should be the value of XXX in my `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XXX'`,when my `buildToolsVersion` is '23.0.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildToolsVersion` is the version of the compilers (aapt, dx, renderscript compiler, etc...) that you want to use.
For each API level (starting with 18), there is a matching .0.0 version.

You can use a higher version of the build-tools than your `compileSdkVersion`, in order to pick up new/better compiler while not changing what you build your app against.

Then you should **use the latest version** of `buildToolsVersion` in any case, independently by the version of support libraries used.

Moreover.
It is strongly **recommended** that you always compile with the latest SDK. 
It means that today you should use `compileSdkVersion` 25.

If you use the **Support Library,** compiling with the latest SDK is a requirement for using the latest Support Library releases. 
For example, to use the 25.0.0 Support Library, you must have a `compileSdkVersion` of at least 25 (those first numbers need to match!).

In other word the **best solution** today should be:

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
compileSdkVersion 25
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0
```

but you can also use:

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
compileSdkVersion 23
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.x.x
```

Comment: but when i am using 25.0.0 i am getting this error

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Information:BUILD FAILED

Comment: @rock19 You should ask a new question with a dedicated topic. It is something different and in this way other can help you in the specific problem. Also add in the question the full error message.

Comment: but this question is already present 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594966/android-studio-2-3-errorjava-util-concurrent-executionexception-java-lang-runt

can you please answer this?

Comment: @rock19 it seems the same, but without the full error is impossible to answer. It can be different causes.

Comment: can you list out the common possible reasons?

Comment: @rock19 No reason to do it. Just run gradlew assemble --info (or debug) and get the full error message.

Comment: I have posted the question regarding this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697478/android-studio-errorjava-util-concurrent-executionexception-java-lang-runtimee

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3'
```

will be better.

Comment: Why should be better 23.0.3 instead of 23.4.0 for example?

Answer (score 0):

Go and check
 in Menu file|Project structure there click Dependencies tab
there you can check for Compile library...also u can change the libraries here using Flavours and Build types Tab

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.2'**
because your buildToolsVersion is '23.0.3'.

Normally whichever your build tools version like in your question it is **23.0.3** is compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**23.0.2** and may be you also using some other dependencies of **com.android.support** there you can use **com.android.support:_________:23.0.2**

Comment: It is not true. Why should it be 23.0.2 instead of 23.4.0 for example? There is not relationships between the fix of buildTools and support libraries for example.

Comment: because of sdk build tools is downloaded in bundle so it does not sure that it must have latest depedencies. Like Example
  
//it requires compileSdkVersion 23
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

Comment: I guess some how the answer is correct because For E.g. when you choose buildToolVersion 23.0.3 and your dependencies version is 21 then it will just give warnings with red line in gradle file to use the 23 dependencies.As per the answer said by Gabriele Mariotti he is also right their is no relationship between buildTools and support lib.But it will give warning only.Sometime it will not generating the signed apk due to this error so its better to use same version support lib.