# Android-Studio Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

```
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2520Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72520Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout101Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2520Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2520Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2520Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2520Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2520Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42520Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2520Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 28351312): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
AAPT err(Facade for 26766318): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
AAPT err(Facade for 874694): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
AAPT err(Facade for 31901794): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

```
AAPT err(Facade for 24683275): /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Thread(png-cruncher_3): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:150)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:247)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Thread(png-cruncher_4): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:150)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:247)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Thread(png-cruncher_2): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:150)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:247)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Thread(png-cruncher_5): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:150)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:247)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

```
Thread(png-cruncher_1): Stream closed

Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Can anyone please tell me the solution for this error?