# Gradle Build gets stuck at Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am running Android Studio 1.3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04, with build-tools version 23.0.0.

Whenever I load any project, after the indexing is complete, Gradle shows Gradle Build Running and no matter how long I leave it, it shows no progress or errors.

I have tried these solutions:

- [How to fix Android Studio getting stuck executing Gradle tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629368/how-to-fix-android-studio-getting-stuck-executing-gradle-tasks)
- [Gradle gets stuck at either 'build' or 'assembleDebug' when using the 64bit or 32bit version of Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345488/gradle-gets-stuck-at-either-build-or-assembledebug-when-using-the-64bit-or-3)
- [Gradle Build stuck at generate debug sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237059/gradle-build-stuck-at-generate-debug-sources)

But they do not work for me.

Any more solutions? Help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem after a lot of trial and error.

- Firstly I changed the build-tools version to 22.0.1. I know this is an outdated version, but it worked for me.
- After that, Gradle build finished with an aapt error, for which I installed the following.

`sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1`

These solved the problem for me.

Comment: This `sudo apt-get install lib32z1` solved my problem.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lib32z1` solved my problem too

Answer (score 1):

> sudo apt-get install lib32z1

This dependency was missing in my Ubuntu.. Got it fixed after installing it

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Changing buildToolsVersion in build gradle file worked for me.