# android studio take too much time without build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I just installed ubuntu version 16.04 and also installed  java version "1.8.0_131". extract the downloaded android studio from google developer website in opt folder and copy SDK from my company desktop system to home/username/Android/SDK. now it is 5 hours and android gradle still not build and stick with this part that says

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

i tested several ways changing IP with VPN, clear ad reRun, Invalid cache/Restart
Past

```
-x :app:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies -x :app:mockableAndroidJar -x :app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources
```

to Settings>Build, Exception,Developer > compiler>Command-line-Options

install following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

which said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360632/gradle-build-gets-stuck-at-executing-tasks-appgeneratedebugsources-appgen) post before

but i still get same issue and the disaster part is that it doesn't give any error.

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit version of Ubuntu or 64-bit?

Comment: @MorrisonChang no it is 64-bit